# Error while OpenCV load yaml file

Tags: c++, opencv, yaml, file-storage

I am trying to load a matrix from .yaml file but OpenCV gives me the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Parsing error (vocabularytraindata.yml(132841098): Missing, between the elements) in icvYMLParseValue.

This is the Write into Storage file, and it works fine:

```
//save the training data
cv::FileStorage fs; 
fs.open(vocabTrainDataPath, cv::FileStorage::WRITE);
fs << "VocabTrainData" << vocabTrainData;
fs.release();
```

This is the code for Reading from storage file:

```
cv::FileStorage fs; 

//load in vocab training data
fs.open(vocabTrainDataPath, cv::FileStorage::READ);
cv::Mat vocabTrainData;
fs["VocabTrainData"] >> vocabTrainData;
```

I am sure that the yaml file has been generated and I have set the file path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. The vocabTrainDataPath I used was just vocabularytraindata.yml before. Because I thought it just placed the same path with the executable file. But when Wrote into Storage file, it succeeded. But Reading from storage file, I need to set the total vocabularytraindata.yml path, from \home. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This did not help in my case. It seems there is a problem with the source code in OpenCV 3.4.1. The workaround is to use the .JSON file extension.